# Setting a member variable to an object outside the class

Tags: c#, variables, reference, parameters

I want to track a variable in my class that was created outside the scope. In C++ i'd just pass a pointer like this.

```
class Camera
{
    Player* player;
    Position pos;

    void setFollow(Player* pl) { pl = player; }
    void update() { pos = pl->getPos(); }
}

int Main()
{
    Camera* camera = new Camera();

    Player* player = new Player();

    camera->setFollow(player);
}
```

In C# I tried to pass by reference but it didnt seem to work.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    Camera cam = new Camera();
    Player player = new Player();

    cam.setFollow(ref player);  // <-- by reference
}
```

This is just a shortened version of my actual code.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Thanks to all for the information.

Comment: that would just pass by value wouldn't it? So when the player updated the camera would not be updated.

Comment: read the answers for explanation there are a lot of them

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't very helpful. What did you expect it to do and what did it do? Also, posting the C# version of `Camera` and its `setFollow` method might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, object (class) variables are implicitly pointers.  So, if your class `Camera` has a field `p` of type `Player`, setting `cam.p = player` in your code would leave both references pointing to the same instance.  There's generally no need to use `ref` unless you're passing value types (`int`, `float`, `structs`, etc) by reference.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to use the `ref` keyword here as objects are always passed by reference in C#.  The `ref` keyword in C# is typically used more like a pointer-to-a-pointer (`**`) would be used in C/C++

Answer (score 0):

Player itself is a reference type why are you using ref. 
You can read more about ref here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Classes are always passed by reference so you don't need the ref bit that you are trying to do

simply

```
cam.setFollow(player);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ref` keyword in C# has a really bad name. It doesn't mean you pass by reference! It should have been named `alias`, because this is the good word that describes the semantic of `ref`.

```
// here I assign a reference(another bad name :) )
// you can also call it Garbage Collector Handler 
// of type Player with a new object
Player player = new Player(); 
// ref means that player is the same thing that parameter pl of setFollow
cam.setFollow(ref player);
```

[More details](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)